# Add an object 'Company' in Moodle

Tags: moodle

I have a question, is possible if i want to add a new object called 'Company' to Moodle?

My Moodle is provides for several Companies. Each company have their staffs. Staff permission is the same with normal user. The problem is 'Company'.

How could i define a new object Company to moodle. For example, i go 'my user profile' and see the information about My Company: ABC Company, and the administrator could manage all the Company (add, edit info, delete)

Thanks in advance

Tuan Anh.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want a profile field called 'company', then that can be added as a custom profile field - http://docs.moodle.org/en/User_profile_fields

If you want to manage multiple, separate organisations via a single Moodle install, then you want to look at multi tenancy - there is no complete solution to this, but there are several approaches - http://www.synergy-learning.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/Multi-tenancy-in-Moodle.pdf is a good overview.

If you want Moodle + support for company hierarchies (and better reporting, etc), then you should consider Totara as an alternative - http://www.totaralms.com/